# Preventing missing controller errors for things that aren't controllers

Tags: cakephp-1.3

My email box is filling up with errors like Error: Robots.txtController could not be found. and Error: CssController could not be found.  I planned to be able to configure cake to not blow missing controller errors on things like favicon.ico, missing images, etc.

The htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^module(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?url=system_fields/route/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I prevent these kinds of errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to fix the errors than to prevent them. For example, if you are seeing Robots.txtController errors, you should add the Robots.txt to your webroot. This will not only prevent the error, it will actually serve up the Robots.txt file when requested. The same would go for the other errors you are seeing.

Comment: I ended up modifying the error message to show the requesting url so I could determine which images were missing.  The favicon one is a bit befuddling because it's actually there and the browser is using it, but periodically the code blows an error stating that it's missing.